# Get value when line has same delimiters multiple times

Tags: bash, awk

I have the line below in a file named `common.txt`:

```
common=cn=yahoo,cn=yahoo1,dc=dcontroller,dc=com
```

I want to extract the value of `common` in a variable. Trying this

```
common=$(awk -F'=' {'print $2'} common.txt)
```

won't work as there are multiple `=` in the line. How can I extract the value of `common` from file using awk?

Expected result:

```
common=cn=yahoo,cn=yahoo1,dc=dcontroller,dc=com
```

Comment: so ... what is the expected value of common ? yahoo ?

Comment: cn=yahoo,cn=yahoo1,dc=dcontroller,dc=com

Comment: So, you just want to get all after the first `common=`? Just use `common="$(sed 's/^common=//' common.txt)"`

Comment: yes..everything after common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution I could think of is(considering that string common comes only 1 time in line), also correcting OP's attempt here too:

```
awk -F'common=' '{print $2}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `sub` of `awk`.

```
awk '{sub(/^common=/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using `match` of `awk`.

```
awk 'match($0,/^common=/){print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***4th solution:*** Using simple `sed` substitution method.

```
sed 's/^common=//' Input_file
```

---

---

***5th solution:*** Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/common=\(.*\)/\1/' Input_file
```

---

---

***6th solution:*** With using shell's `while` loop though it may NOT be fast like above solutions, adding it as a variant here.

```
while IFS="=" read line1 line2
do
  echo "$line2"
done < "Input_file"
```

---

---

***7th solution:*** Using `while` loop bash one along with process substitution.

```
while read line
do
  echo "${line#*=}"
done < "Input_file"
```

For all command's output wrap them into like `common=$(above anyone command)` will save output into a variable named `common`.

Answer (score 1):

As the contents of the file appears to be in bash variable-setting format, why don't you just do:

```
source common.txt
```

?

Comment: simple, does someone find an inconvenient to this solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cut` with `=` as the delimiter and print all fields starting with the second:

```
$ cut -d= -f2- common.txt
cn=yahoo,cn=yahoo1,dc=dcontroller,dc=com
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk will not be the best tool in my opinion as your file is not a proper delimited seperated value

Use GNU grep :

```
grep -oP '^common=\K.*' <file>
```

Output :

```
cn=yahoo,cn=yahoo1,dc=dcontroller,dc=com
```

To extract it into a variable :

```
common="$(grep -oP '^common=\K.*' <file>)"
```

Comment: @oguzismail I understand. I still don't like using awk for this kind of files. sed would be maybe better, as suggested by Wiktor Stribiżew. Anyway I like grep here because it works well even if you add lines to common file. You are right pointing its lack of portability.